# Gallery using FancyBox

Tags: fancybox

I'm trying to add fancy box to the photos part of my website currently in progress...

When i click on the image it doesn't show up like it is supposed to. Instead, it goes to its own separate url to show the image.

I have tried watching a few tutorial videos to help but nothing has worked.  I believe I have all the right code (for the first two images at least).

Could you please look at my code and assist me in anyway possible?
http://www.chrislcarrier.com/photos.html

This is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="img/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/…; 
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".fancyImg").fancybox({ 
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic', 
            'speedIn'   :   600, 
            'speedOut'  :   200, 
            'width' : 1200px, 
            'height' : 800px, 
            'overlayShow'   :   false 
         }); 
     }); 
</script>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a class="fancyImg" href="img/water.png">
                <img id="move" src="img/water_small.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <hr class="hidden-lg">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a class="fancyImg" href="img/flower_large.jpg">
                <img id="move2" src="img/flower_small.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <hr class="hidden-lg">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="move3" src="img/view_small.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant code and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: This is my code.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="img/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

 
 
 
 
 $(".fancyImg").fancybox({
  
  'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
  'speedIn'  : 600, 
  'speedOut'  : 200, 
  'width'         :   1200px,
  'height'        :   800px,
  'overlayShow' : false
  
 });
 
});
</script>

Comment: <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a class="fancyImg" href="img/water.png"><img id="move" src="img/water_small.jpg" alt=""></a><hr class="hidden-lg"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a class="fancyImg" href="img/flower_large.jpg"><img id="move2" src="img/flower_small.jpg" alt=""></a><hr class="hidden-lg"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img id="move3" src="img/view_small.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
     
            
     </div>

Comment: It should work on the first two images as they have the class "fancyImg"

no?

Comment: I ended up changing to the newest version of fancy box 2.0 I believe. I followed all the setup instructions and it still wouldn't work. I double checked my code and was calling 2 jQuery library's which is what I guess the problem was?

Comment: But thankfully it works now and I can continue to build my site, work in progress :)   http://www.chrislcarrier.com/photos.html